# AngularJS change css property value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Following are my html snippet:

```
<div class="pay row-0 col-1 ">
        <div class="t-middle f26 f-white row-0 " style="position:absolute;top:50%;">please wait...</div>
</div>
```

And the stylesheet for `.pay` class are as follow:

```
.pay, .stopIE {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

When a button is clicked, the following function is executed.

```
$scope.goBuy = function(){
    Account.buyNow({"pid": $scope.buypp.id})
        .then(function(response){
            [change the .pay class display to block]
            $window.location.href = response.data;
        })

        .catch(function(response){

        })
}
```

While waiting for the response, how can I change the `.pay` class `display` property value from `none` to `block`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/Hide for such things with a proper scope variable. For more control (if you need), you can also use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) or [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) (preferrably).